# Pass interface from Fragment to class

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I have problem with using interface. In my fragment i made interface and i want use it in class (with adapter), class is not an activity. Class implements interface from fragment and i try use intent like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Adapter.class);
        intent.putExtra("interface", inter);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    removelist inter = (removelist) intent.getSerializableExtra("interface");
```

where in the adapter i should contain this, and is this a correct solution?

Comment: From your code it seems that you are trying to open activity named Adapter(which you mentioned as "not an activity")

So what exactly are you trying to achieve here with interface??

Comment: What is Adapter.class, is it your activity? Question is not clear at all....

Comment: what are u planning to achieve ?

Comment: i want to make interface which will be work in adapter.class on click on menu in fragment

Answer (score 0):

You definitely doing something wrong. I do not think that starting an activity and passing a callback of any kind to it is a good idea, at leas architecture-wise

Comment: so how i can use interfaces in Adapter.class from Fragment?